# Making sure types are correct for all the contents of a record type recursively in OCaml

Tags: recursion, types, ocaml

I'm not sure if there is a better way to do this but was wondering how can I make sure that all the types of a record are accurate. I tried the following code below (making a recursive function to search the record) and was going to put matches for every level / scenario... I'm somewhat new to OCaml (more of a C and Python guy) so I'm struggling with this syntax.

```
type typeA= Int | Bool | List of typeA

type highestLevelObject= typeA* typeB and typeB= 
  |Float of float
  | BoolLit of bool
  | Int of int
  | Seq of highestLevelObjectlist
  | Bool of bool

(* The function to ensure my Object came in good *)
let rec verifyFields (highestLevelObject: highestLevelObject): bool = 
match highestLevelObject with 
| int-> true
| bool -> true
| _ -> verifyFields highestLevelObject
```

This compiles with warnings...
Warning 10: this expression should have type unit. (regarding  _ -> case)
Warning 11: this match case is unused. (regarding _ -> case and  bool -> case)
oddly

There must be something special with the List and getting a base case here...  is matching each type manually or if there is a better(more elegant) way to do this?
Looking at https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/data_types_and_matching.html also but still struggling.

Comment: You seem to be confusing variable names and type names.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't use `of` in pattern matching.

Comment: changed the line of code from List of typeA to type A and the error changed from syntax error to "Error: The constructor false expects 0 argument(s),
       but is applied here to 1 argument(s)" so I think it needs to be some sort of list?

Comment: I removed `of` and got `Error: Unbound type constructor highestLevelObjectlist`. Not sure what you're doing.

Comment: that's odd let me update the question to reflect latest code and err... I wonder if I'm on right path.

Comment: You've changed `Int` to `int` in the pattern, so now it's equivalent to `foo` or `x` or any other variable name. It matches any value and binds it to the (new) local variable `int`.

Comment: hmm so to begin with I should match on the names from the type (Int, Bool, BoolLit , and Seq)? and then for Int and Bool I check the type using what operator? and for BoolLit I can call recursively ?

Comment: I don't understand what your code is supposed to do. `Int` is a constructor, not a type.

Comment: So basically given some highestLevelObject I want to return true if it's valid and false otherwise. Let's say I passed in   (Int x, Seq [ (List Int, Seq [(Int, IntLit 4);]);(List Int, Seq []) ])  I would return false because our first element is not a float

Comment: What do you mean by "highestLevelObject" and "valid"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the pattern matching, you should deconstruct data using data constructors, like this

```
match highestLevelObject with
| Int -> true
| Bool -> true
| Seq objs -> ...
| _ -> false
```

Notice the capitalized `Int` which is the *data constructor*, contrary to `int` which is just a variable name, so when you write

```
match highestLevelObject with
| int -> ...
```

it is the same as saying

```
match highestLevelObject with
| anything -> ...
```

in fact, `anything` here could be any variable name, which will match any data and bind itself to it. In other words, `match x with y -> f y` is the same as `let y = x in f y`

Comment: Awesome i get the int vs Int from @melpomene above thankfully, but Thanks for giving the direction ivg on how I should match highestLevelObject  I guess I will need the recursive call in the Seq objs ... this part will be challenge